# How to event track a field output

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a loan calculator on my website, the last field outputs whether they are accepted or unnaccepted when the calculate button is clicked.

How would I set up event tracking for it to track how many were accepted and how many weren't?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit hard to answer without seeing the actual calculator (which might be anything from a simple form to an embedded iframe or a flash or java widget, which all would require different implementations).

Comment: Put break points to debug your app. And the place is hit for your conditions, place the event tracker with label. Maybe you share your code to get insights.